# Background Color affecting forms layers in winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

It's not a real problem, just asking a question out of curiosity.

I have added an additional form in my C# winforms application and made it transparent and changed its property `Enabled` to `false`. If `TransparentKey` of my child form is `White`, `Black` or `Gray`, I can interact with the control behind it in main form. But if transparent key is any other color other then grayscale like `Blue` or `Red`, i cant interact with the control behind my form.

In summary, I want to interact with the control behind my transparent child form and i have no problem setting its `TransparentKey` to any grayscale colors. But why does changing the transparent key affects the layer of forms?

[image: example image]

Take a look at this image, I'm hovering over button1 and can actually press it. Not the same case when form above main form does not have transparent key as grayscale color.

Comment: transparency in win forms is horrible! But there's quite a lot of questions here on SO about it, you should look some of them up!

Comment: ow.. -1 for post.. yet they said you're not able to post images until u reach reputation 10.. can i ask the reason for -1?? -__-

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably cause this is a bit off-topic for SO, esp when there isn't actually a explicit programming question here. MyAdvice - try editing your question SLIGHTLY so to make it helpful/more explicit to read/answerable.

Comment: thank you for suggestions. maybe i've been using informal words. I have seen couple of questioned related to designing answered at SO, so I thought of posting my question here.

Comment: just add a bit of code relating to where this is happening, along with a 'cleaner' description - and you will find that SO is a great resource!

Comment: It is a bug in Aero, turned on by default in Windows versions since Vista.  Distinct from the way color keying was done before, the video adapter used to take care of it.  Now done in software by the DWM.  It fumbles the mouse transparency for *certain* color keys, like Color.Red or Color.Blue.  The exact nature of the bug is intractable, there isn't much rhyme or reason to the kind of key colors where Aero fumbles.  You need to pick your key color carefully to avoid this bug.  Prefer Color.Fuchia or Color.Lime,  colors that are very unlikely to be used anywhere else in the window.

Comment: yup. color.lime works.. my assumption about grayscale colors was wrong.